# What is the most potent method of scar resurfacing?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery, laser

For now, there are different methods of scar resurfacing:

- Laser
- Fraxel
- Radio Frequency therapy
- CO2-Laser
- Microneedling with/without PRP
- Nd:YAG laser
- Dermabrasion/Microdermabrasion

---

Maybe some others? Which method of invasive scar treatments is more effective in minimizing scars and has fewer side effects?